# PySpark - Dataframe Column value manipulation error

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with below 4 columns :

**date | code | sub_cat | sales**

Where the data type of the last column : sales is float .

I want to apply a numpy log function to that column only and below is what i am doing .

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

log_func = udf(lambda x : np.log(x))

df.withColumn("sales",log_func(df['sales'])).show()
```

Below is the error that i get :

**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o278.showString.**

Any help would be appreciated as i am not sure whats wrong with my code .

Comment: Can you include the full traceback and a small sample of your data? My initial guess is that you may have a 'null', `0`, or negative value in your `sales` column.

Comment: I should also point out there there's no need for a `udf` here - you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.log`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.log): `from pyspark.sql.functions import log; df.withColumn("sales",log('sales')).show()`